# How to use local accounts on samba machine

Tags: samba, network-share, share

I have a linux system running samba which has an ethernet connection to a Windows 7 PC. After reading and trying a lot I got the following configuration:

```
[myShare]
path = /usr/share/mySystemUser/
public = yes
guest ok = yes
writeable = yes
browseable = yes
ntlm auth = no
```

I simply want that *myShare* can be accessed **either**

1. without any password (public share) **or**
2. with the credentials of *mySystemUser*. *mySystemUser* is a local user on the linux machine.

But so far Windows requests a password, therefore *myShare* can only be accessed if I run

```
useradd myWindowsUserName
smbpasswd -a myWindowsUsername
```

While entering the same Password as on the Windows machine, so that the same username exists both on the linux and Windows7 machine with the same password.

How can 1. and 2. be solved?

Answer (score 2):

I am using this configuration

```
[public]
  comment = Public Folder
  path = /home/public
  public = yes
  writable = yes
  create mask = 0777
  directory mask = 0777
  force user = nobody
  force group = nogroup
```

and in case mySystemUser = myWindowsUserName

```
[mySystemUser]
    path = /usr/share/mySystemUser/
    browseable = no
    writeable = yes
    create mode = 0770
    directory mode = 0770
    read only = no
    valid users = mySystemUser
    force user = mySystemUser
```

If you wanna to see your shared folder in windows explorer, set browseable to yes.